# How to run an existing function from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook. In the same folder in which the notebook is running, I have a function f defined as

```
 def f(x):
    return x**2
```

I have saved this function as f.py in the same folder. Now I want to call this function in the notebook that is running. How do I do that? If the function was typed into the notebook, I could have just typed

```
f(4)
```

Comment: You need to import f.py. If in the same directory, run `from f import f`

Comment: @rahul_88 are you still having difficulty?

Comment: @JamesDraper yeah..still difficulty...."ImportError: No module named cluster_ap"

Comment: @rahul_88 what command is giving you this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the `load` magic;

```
%load f.py
```

That automatically loads the in the entire contents of file so that you can edit it in a cell.

```
from f import f
```

Is another option.

If neither one of those work for you could try adding your notebook's directory to the the system path by running this block as a cell before trying to call your function;

```
import os
import sys
nb_dir = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
if nb_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(nb_dir)
```

Comment: I dont want to load the function since that will make the notebook messy.....regarding the second choice, is it a universal rule to use 
from function name import function . ? what if there is a double names..say I have a function that is named after existing libraries?

Comment: No you could name the file anything that you want. The file and the functions/classes/variables in the file can have completely different names.

Comment: > what if there is a double names..say I have a function that is named after existing libraries? This is called a namespace collision much has been written on this but what it boils down to is that it is best to give your functions and classes unique names.

Comment: @rahul_88 would you please accept it and upvote? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sure....one more thing..the file name must be given as 'name.py'? or just name.py?

Comment: So if the file name was name.py with function f then you'd import it like this `from name import f`

Comment: It gave an error "ImportError: No module named cluster_ap"......I hope I am not making some trivial mistake

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac OS

Answer (score 8):

```
%run f.py
```

`load` magic was just copying the whole file into a cell, which was not what i need. Neither did the importing worked for me. was throwing some weird errors. So i ended up using the `run` magic.

Comment: I ended up using this option because using import loaded an old version of  f.py after I modified it.